# How to make this join with a TSQL query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have a table called `USERS` that has a foreign key to the table `GROUPS` (a user can pertain to one or none `GROUPS`). The table `USERS` also contains a column `ISDELETED` (a char column with `T` or `F`).

I need a query to retrieve all the `GROUPS` and all the `USERS` that are not deleted, if all the users in a `GROUP` are deleted or no users are defined I need the query to return NULL for that `GROUP`.

I tried with the following query:

```
SELECT     GROUPS.*, USERS.*
FROM       GROUPS INNER JOIN
                  USERS ON GROUPS.ID = USERS.GROUPID
WHERE USERS.ISDELETED = 'F'
```

But this query does not returns the groups that are empty. SQL and me are not the best friends in world, some help will be great, thanks.

Comment: for joins see a visual explanation from jeff atwood at: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the groups, regardless of a match in the users table, you should use a left outer join:

```
SELECT     GROUPS.*, USERS.*
FROM       GROUPS 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           USERS 
           ON GROUPS.ID = USERS.GROUPID AND USERS.ISDELETED = 'F'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to do a left outer join -

```
SELECT     GROUPS.*, USERS.*
FROM       GROUPS LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  USERS ON GROUPS.ID = USERS.GROUPID
WHERE USERS.ISDELETED = 'F'
```

[Here's](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) a reference I like to use to remind myself of the differences in sql joins.

Comment: With a WHERE it does not work, it has to be inside the ON of the join. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` operator instead of the `INNER JOIN`.